# What is a good way to implement a search form?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, design-patterns

I am looking for some inspiration to implement a search engine for my winforms application. I have a 'root' class which has 5 'child' classes as properties. So imagine that class A us my root class and it has the following properties:

- Id
- Name
- ClassB
- ClassC
- ClassD
- ClassE

In the database classA is represented by table A and it has foreign key references to tables B, C, D and E. This relation between A and B,C,D,E are 1:1.

In my application I need to build am advanced search form. So I have a lot of checkboxes, radiobuttons and textboxes. This form must search in all the tables (A,B,C,D,E).

How would you implement this?

If it is necessary to know, I am using the Entity Framework.

Comment: As side note on the UI consider the IE9 and Chrome approach to have a single textbox for standard search and you combine results of multiple search in multiple fields. IMHO this is the modern and useful way which will reduce needs to even open the adv. search. like in Android you are in the search and it finds sites, emails, messages, contacts, apps....

Comment: I like the idea, but I don;t think I can use this manner because the end user wants to filter on amount of people, total costs, living in the area A, etc.

Comment: Simple solution only as starting point and not considering nested entities would be do a search with multiple parts in the WHERE checking text present in different fields all in OR. only as a start... lets see what experts will answer to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about "flattening" your data using a schema bound view and creating a full text index? Your primary search box and modifiers could be used to manipulate the FTS query.